# Moving files in directory into subdirectories with matching names

Tags: linux

I have a directory of files that all start with some prefix {0000..0030} and all follow a naming convention like this: `0000_0000_124_23.png, 0000_0001_124_23.png, 0001_0001_124_23.png, ...`

I created subdirectories corresponding to the prefixes of the files `0000/, 0001/, ...` and am trying to move files into subdirectories that match their prefix. I've tried `for i in {00..30}; do mv 00$i_*.png 00$i/; done` but that seems to only move all the files into one subdirectory. How can I ensure that the files go into the correct folders?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
00$i_*.png
```

An underscore is a valid character in an identifier name, but the variable `$i_` is empty, so it expands to

```
00*.png
```

and moves all the files.

### Solution

Separate the variable name from the underscore.

```
00$i\_*.png
```

or

```
00${i}_*.png
```